# Unable to take incremental backup in DB2

Tags: db2

I have DB running with TRACKMOD ON but when ever i try to take incremental backup using the command ' backup db  online incremental to ' it gives me an error
" SQL2426N The database has not been configured to allow the incremental backup operation. Reason code = reason-code."

When i check db2diag log it say " Incremental backup was not enabled for table space SYSCATSPACE because the TRACKMOD configuration parameter was not enabled."

I have taken the backup of SYSCATSPACE and TRACKMOD is also ON still same error. can anyone help !!

Comment: First I would verify that TRACKMOD really is enabled: `db2 get db cfg for <db> show detail`. If it is, I would try taking a full offline backup of the database, and then retry the incremental backup.

Comment: @Lennart is correct.  Until you have taken a full backup of the database after enabling `TRACKMOD`, you won't be able to take an incremental backup.

Comment: I have rechecked it says "Track Modified Pages ON".. i have also taken an full online backup using "backup db <name> online to <path>" but still it gives the same error.

Comment: Guys issue is resolved...i should have taken offline backup after enabling TRACKMOD...now its working

Comment: This question does not belong to SOF, but to database administrators site.

Answer (score 1):

First do a full backup (online/offline), then an incremental backup will work

```
db2 backup db sampledb to /dev/null
db2 backup db sampledb incremental to /dev/null
```

For Windows use "NUL:" instead of "/dev/null"